# Can you search a listview without having a listview item in your Activity XML file? (Android)

Tags: android, listview, search

I was trying to search my activity that has a list view stored in it. The list view is stored as one big string. I was wondering if there was a way to search this, I have tried and many sources have said to create a listview in the XML but that would require a big code change for multiple activities. Here is my code. Any help is appreciated!

```
static String[] Beverages_Recipes = { "CHOCOLATE MARTINI", "FOOLER COOLER", "HOT COCOA MIX", "KOOLAID PUNCH", "ORANGE JULIUS I",
        "ORANGE JULIUS II", "PARTY PUNCH", "SANGRIA", "SOUTHERN COMFORT PUNCH", "SUNSHINE PUNCH", "TOM AND JERRY MIX"};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Beverages_Recipes));
}
```

So I just want to be able to search the string Beverages_Recipes. And display the results in a drop down type box. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) for doing a drop down menu. which it will take an adapter that you specify its own array String[] which is `Beverages_Recipes` in your case.

Here is a nice simple [tutorial](http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2013/07/simple-autocompletetextview-example.html) about it.

Hope this is what you are looking for, inform me otherwise. happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. I'd advise you to use the SearchView that is built into the action bar. You can learn how to implement the search view by following the guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html